# UWP programmatically remove visualstate for specific listviewitem

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, uwp-xaml, listviewitem

My style is defined for the listview.
Listview items will have focus behaviour.

I have 3 types in my ListView.
One is unselectable and will also not having focus behaviour (used property `IsHitTestVisible = false`)
One is selectable, can have focus colors (works correctly)
One should be selectable but only should not having a focus state.

`IsEnabled` changes the transparancy and is unselectable so no option.
`IsHitTestVisible` doesnt change the transparancy but make the item also unclickable.

Do anyone have an example how I can remove only the focus behaviour but keep the rest for a specific item?

Comment: Is this Xamarin or UWP? Why tag both? I understand in some cases things are the same but in this case it's confusing since the XAML part is very different.

Comment: @JustinXL Xamarin is cross platform, so Xamarin UWP, where my problem is in the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **ViewCellRenderer** for your listview. For Reference you can use this link:

http://blog.wislon.io/posts/2017/04/11/xamforms-listview-selected-colour

Comment: Here he mentioned also

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell/#Creating_the_Custom_Renderer_on_Windows_Phone_and_UWP

Comment: You are right, unfortunately is this Xamarin Forms, I only use Xamarin with MvvmCross. Xamarin Forms has its own components which has this event introduced.